# How increase a value of a field that is in a database daily?

Tags: java, mysql, timertask

I'm doing a program in java and I'm trying to make is that every time you pass one day, a field that I have in a database to increase in value. I need your help I have no idea how.

Comment: Which part?  Incrementing a value in the database ([for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850393/incrementing-an-integer-in-sql-server)) or scheduling a daily task to update it?

Comment: you will need `sqljob` (which is not `java`, it's `sql`) or `task scheduler`

Comment: do you want mysql to do this automatically without java?